# Save XML document to disk how to deal with &amp; in sitemap.xml?

Tags: php, xml, sitemap

I have a php code that creates an XML and it works fine, but it messes up the `&` and converts it to `&amp;`

I use this code to put my url into the xml:

> htmlentities($final_url);

and when xml file is opened, it shows

`index.php?route=product/product&amp;path=37&amp;product_id=1101515800&amp;pdescription`

How can I format it properly?

Comment: Why do you use `htmlentities` on an url ? use `urlencode` instead.

Comment: Do you open the XML file in an XML editor or in a text editor? If you see raw XML, the &amp; instead of the & is actually correct XML syntax.

Comment: @j0k: He wants to escape the URL in context of XML, not in context of a URL, so while not being quite correct, htmlentities() is better than urlencode().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code is working correctly. An ampersand in XML must always be encoded as `&amp;`. You don't need to worry about it, because anyone reading the file using an XML parser will have it automatically decoded as `&`. The only time you need to worry is if someone is reading the file without using a real parser (e.g. using a regex) and regular followers of this forum will know that is a very dangerous thing to do.